# PHP & MySQL: Can 'insert on duplicate update' queries interfere?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

Given a table like this:

```
id |  counter
 1 |   3
```

(the field `id` is primary) and the following query:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `test`(`id`, `counter`) VALUES (1,1) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter= counter+1' 
$db->query($sql);
```

Would it be possible that that two different user execute this script from the server and the counter only gets updated to `4` instead of `5`, because they were executed at the same time and increased both `3` to `4` at once? Or is this not possible?

Comment: use lock table https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: @Fky so you say its possible that they interfere?

Comment: Yes , if scripts are executed with two different sessionid , it can trouble , so i advice to use lock table to disallow other action on table while request exectued and free at end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `LOCK TABLE` with InnoDB.  It is essentially never necessary.

IODKU locates the one row, locks it, then performs the operation, then unlocks.  No problem with multiple 'simultaneous' connections, except that one will wait (a *tiny* amount of time) for the other to release the lock.

What you have is a good table for "Likes" (social media) or "Hits" (web pages).  Note that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, but *not* `auto_increment`.  It is the same `id` as for the main table (which probably has `auto_increment`).

If you have more than hundreds of likes/hits per *second*, there will be performance problems.  (But that is another discussion.)  Obviously, you are not there yet.